# how to insert a HTML form into a javascript popup?

Tags: plugins, javascript, html, contact

I'm working on a plugin that generates a list of candidates as output. For each candidate there is a link (View Details) that once is clicked, a popup appears. I need to put a simple contact form into that popup, so when a visitor click on the candidate's link, the popup appear and the visitor can get into touch with the website owner and ask references about that candidate.

As I said, all this is done by a plugin. I'm having problems in making a simple modal contact form from that plugin. Any idea in how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) It's not a WP Question as long as it's not a specific plugin (link?).

B) Do it with jQuery:

```
var str = <?php echo $user_id.'etc.'; ?>;
var container = jQuery( '#contact_form_popup_id' ).html();
jQuery( container ).text( str );
```